# Adding header button in Odoo 16

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

I'm trying to add header button to a tree view in Odoo 16 I created for a custom module.

Here is the view :

```
    <record id="cc_order_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">cc.order.list</field>
        <field name="model">cc.order</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree>
                <header>
                    <button name="action_mark_as_discarded" string="Discard" class="oe_highlight" type="object" data-hotkey="d"></button>
                </header>
                <field name="number" />
                <field name="itemsTotal" />
                <field name="total" />
                <field name="odoo_status" />
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

However, button never shows. I tried to check how it's done in other views but it seems there are different ways to do so. Also, documentation is quite vague about adding new elements. Any idea which is the correct way to add this button ?

Comment: The code looks right. Sorry but i have to ask :-( did you mark some list entries? Because without marking entries the buttons are hidden.

Comment: I tried to select entries but no difference

Answer (score 0):

Odoo will try to validate the tree view and will fail because the button defines a [data-hotkey](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/odoo/addons/base/rng/common.rng#L336-L377) attribute which is not allowed in tree views

To fix this issue remove the `data-hotkey` attribute. The button should appear when you select records

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a way looking at other modules.

Here's the code :

Template :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">

<t t-name="CoopcycleOrders.Buttons" t-inherit="web.ListView.Buttons" t-inherit-mode="primary" owl="1">
    <xpath expr="(//div/*)[last()]" position="after">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary o_button_orders_sync me-2" t-on-click="onClickSyncCoopcycle">
            Sync with Coopcycle
        </button>
    </xpath>
</t>

</templates>
```

JS view :

```
  /** @odoo-module */

import { listView } from "@web/views/list/list_view";
import { CoopcycleOrdersListController } from "./coopcycle_orders_list_controller";
import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";

export const CoopcycleOrdersReportListView = {
    ...listView,
    Controller: CoopcycleOrdersListController,
    buttonTemplate: 'CoopcycleOrders.Buttons',
};

registry.category("views").add('coopcycle_orders_report_list', CoopcycleOrdersReportListView);
```

JS Controller :

```
    /** @odoo-module */

import { useBus } from "@web/core/utils/hooks";
import { session } from "@web/session";
import { ListController } from "@web/views/list/list_controller";

export class CoopcycleOrdersListController  extends ListController {
    setup() {
        super.setup();
        if (this.props.context.inventory_mode || this.props.context.inventory_report_mode) {
            useBus(this.model, "record-updated", this.recordUpdated);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handler called when the user clicked on the 'Sync with Coopcycle' button.
     * Opens wizard to display, at choice, the products inventory or a computed
     * inventory at a given date.
     */
    async onClickSyncCoopcycle() {
         const context = {
            active_model: this.props.resModel,
         };

         this.actionService.doAction({
            res_model: "coopcycle.order.query",
            views: [[false, "form"]],
            target: "new",
            type: "ir.actions.act_window",
            context: context
         })
    }
}
```

Pop up view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="view_coopcycle_order_query" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Coopcycle order query</field>
        <field name="model">coopcycle.order.query</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Choose your dates">
                <group>
                    <field name="begin"/>
                </group><group>
                    <field name="end"/>
                </group>
                <footer>
                    <button name="open_for_dates" string="Confirm" type="object" class="btn-primary" data-hotkey="q"/>
                    <button string="Cancel" class="btn-secondary" special="cancel" data-hotkey="z" />
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```